# Is it okay to have more than one architectural patterns for the same project in ios

Tags: ios, architectural-patterns

We are using `MVC` as our architectural pattern and  hope to use `MVP` or `VIPER`,pattern for some parts of the project. is it okay to have more than one architectural pattern in the same project. is this a good practice?.

Answer (score 3):

My response is a bit anecdotal but I think it is more than ok. As new architectures come out, especially ones that are superior to the old conventions, it only makes sense to move on/try the them. Now the question is should you just indefinitely leave it that way and I would say no. When you have the time/will you should definitely refactor it to the new architecture. That is just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question @Marlon. First of all I want to tell you that, it's all about responsibility segregation among VIPER components such as View, Controller, Interactor, Presenter, Routing.

It's more about tastes one changes over the time during development. There are many architectural patterns out there like MVC, MVVP, MVVM etc. Over time when our taste changes, we change from MVC to VIPER. Someone changes from MVVP To VIPER.

Use your sound vision by keeping class size small in number of lines. You can keep datasource methods in ViewController itself Or create a custom object that conforms to UITableViewDatasoruce protocol.

My aim to keep view controllers slim and every method and class follow Single responsibility principle.

Viper helps to create highly cohesive and low coupled software.

Before using this model of development, one should have sound understanding of distribution of responsibility among classes.

Once you have basic understanding of Oops and Protocols in iOS. You will find this model as easy as MVC.

No problem you can start using a new pattern for a new module or refactor for the existing one. One has to start from somewhere.

All this comes under Hold off architecture erosion as time passes and application evolves.